# How can I pass arguments to a custom sbt task from the command line?

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a custom sbt task  myTask, which accepts list of arguments.

The task is running fine on the sbt console.

```
sbt_proj> mytask arg1
```

I want to run this task on the command line :

```
$ sbt myTask arg1
```

Unfortunately i can't get this  working.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote it, ie:

```
$ sbt 'myTask arg1'
```

Otherwise it will interpret it as two commands, such as if you were trying to run `sbt clean compile`